# Microsoft Graph Cloning API, Channel isFavoriteByDefault issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, cloning

I am cloning a team from another team using Graph API
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
All the channels are present in the newly created team.
However, the channels are shown hidden by default.
'isFavoriteByDefault' property of all the channel is set to true in the source team on the other hand 'isFavoriteByDefault' is set to false in the cloned team.
Channels 'Show for me' and 'Show for Members' settings are also set to true.

Comment: Is this behaviour causing something to break on your end? `isFavoriteByDefault`  is set to false by default and can only be set to true in the call to create team see channel property documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph Clone a team API Copies all settings within the team, along with key group setting but not a channel settings. `isFavoriteByDefault`Can only be set programmatically with [Create team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.